# Paypal chained payments with MPL failing with error 520002 in live environment

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Last week this was working just fine, now Paypal chained payments with MPL fails with 520002 error in our live environment. paymentFailedWithCorrelationID callback returns this in the responsemessage

```
category = Application;
errorId = 520002;
message = "Internal Error";
severity = None;
```

I opened a ticket with paypal support 2 days ago and have not heard a word. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post some example code? or a correlationid to help me find it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. correlationID:1005db947bdb7

Comment: Sorry, this is going to need to be looked at by the technical support team. You'll have to wait on the ticket.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to expedite the issue? I opened the ticket 2 days ago.